# What is the meaning of "use a different clock" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

The following sentence is quoted from [NBC NEWS](https://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/meet-press-11-08-20-n1247045). A journalist talked about the White House:

> And what has not changed in this very long week, Chuck, is the president himself. There remains a Trump way of doing things and that is right on brand for Donald Trump where there's no concession, and fight is on the agenda. So the Trump team is **using a different clock**. The president sees room to pursue this battle because states have not certified election results.

What does "using a different clock" mean? Is it an idiom?

Comment: It's not an established idiom. The writer is trying to avoid using anything like *[Trump] **marches to a different drum, singing a different tune,...*** because *those* metaphorical usages are usually spoken ***approvingly***. And this writer almost certainly *hates* Trump, so even if he wasn't trying to avoid using cliches, he wouldn't want to use an expression with potentially positive overtones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the Trump team is doing things on its own schedule, not doing things at the customary time, such as recognizing the results of the election as legitimate. As far as I know, "using a different clock" isn't an established idiom, but it's immediately understandable to a native speaker.